# Tracking down the origin of a cryptic CoreServicesUIAgent window

Tags: macos

I have been haunted by strange and very vague windows the past week or so. [image: Screenshot]

I will get 5 or 6 if my laptop is suspended for an extended period of time. They appear out of nowhere without any sort of input from me. I've traced the pid to CoreServicesUIAgent and ran a "sample" of it with Activity Monitor to try and trace the call but I am more confused now than I was when I started as I am not a macos dev. I did see two calls with "???" as their names:

```
2545 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 562  [0x7ff807df97ac]
    +                   2545 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 2609  [0x7ff807dfa89d]
    +                     2545 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks  (in CoreFoundation) + 445  [0x7ff807dfb52c]
    +                       2545 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__  (in CoreFoundation) + 12  [0x7ff807dfb681]
    +                         2545 ???  (in CoreServicesUIAgent)  load address 0x107e9f000 + 0x15190  [0x107eb4190]
    +                           2545 ???  (in CoreServicesUIAgent)  load address 0x107e9f000 + 0x2c726  [0x107ecb726]
    +                             2545 -[NSAlert runModal]  (in AppKit) + 121  [0x7ff80ab5a8d2]
    +                               2545 _NSTryRunModal  (in AppKit) + 100  [0x7ff80aacffae]
    +                                 2545 __19-[NSAlert runModal]_block_invoke  (in AppKit) + 70  [0x7ff80ac39f7c]
    +                                   2545 __19-[NSAlert runModal]_block_invoke_2  (in AppKit) + 147  [0x7ff80ac3a022]
    +                                     2545 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]  (in AppKit) + 128  [0x7ff80aacfe95]
    +                                       2545 _NSTryRunModal  (in AppKit) + 100  [0x7ff80aacffae]
```

It seems to happen right when the modal is invoked, but I'm assuming that's done by a somewhat paranoid kernel and not some creepy malware. Hopefully. I've done a malware check and nothing is popping up, but that might not mean anything. I guess that's why I'm here--to figure out if I need to reinstall my OS or not.

Are there any better ways to figure out what is making this window pop up (and therefore make it stop)? Is this some weird zero-day thing? Should I be concerned or am I unjustifiably paranoid? Either way, it's super annoying and I'd like it to end one way or another. Thanks for your time!

EDIT: I'm running Monterey 12.3 on a 2018 MBP 15in

Comment: I think you are on the wrong Stack Exchange for this question, but I have the same issue... I don't think it's a security concern I think it's most likely something changed in the OS, and something (third-party) that used to work fine now has a bug...

Comment: So I followed some leads, and I think I fixed at least one possible source of this issue: desktop pictures. The os upgrade moves the desktop pictures folders around, and doesn't preserve old values. So I noticed that my desktop picture for one of my monitors was showing a question mark in system preferences. I changed that, and no longer see the dialog, for the last few hours.